# Arrange different size div blocks

Tags: css, html, layout

I need to make website layout where I have blocks with "regular dimensions" and "2x2 regular size" blocks and they should be arranged nice, not matter where I put bigger and where I put smaller block. For example if I have situation like this at the pic below, I need block 8 to be below to 5, and block 9 would be next to 8 (below block 6) and so on.

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epWJo.png

Here is my CSS so far:

```
    .block
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 141px;
    height: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    background: lightgray;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.block4
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 294px;
    height: 308px;
    border-style: solid;
    background: lightgray;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Can you please help me how to make it?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your HTML and perhaps even recreate the issue in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/arDkp/

Answer (score 0):

Isotope or jQuery Masonary works well for what you want

```
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://masonry.desandro.com/
```

Comment: is it possible to do it only with CSS? I know css is messy, but... It would be better for my project to do it with only css and html

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done unless you want to put your 1/4 sized blocks in a container. So that the container is floated to the left then contains 4 of the smaller blocks. Or you could use jQuery Masonry as others have said.